# Characterize a $\sigma$-algebra generated by a family of sets $\sigma(C)=\mathcal{B}_{\Omega}$

Tags: measure-theory, set-theory, ordinals, transfinite-recursion

Well, my intention is basically to understand what is done in the answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2603079/characterize-sigma-algebra-generated-by-a-set), which I will summarize in the following... and discuss a little more (hence I made a new question).

> **Problem:** Given a family $C$ of subsets of the real numbers, how can we characterize all elements from the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the family $C$?

In this [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2603079/characterize-sigma-algebra-generated-by-a-set) the answer is almost clear to me, but there are some facts I'd like to discuss.

> **Construction**: For any family $\mathcal{B}\subseteq\mathcal{P}(\Bbb{R})$, we define $\mathcal{B}_c :=\{\bigcup_{k\in \Bbb{N}}A_k: A_k \in \mathcal{B}\}\cup \{A^c: A\in \mathcal{B}\}$ the set which elements are all possible countable unions of elements of $\mathcal{B}$ and also all complements of sets in $\mathcal{B}$.
>
> Now consider $\mathcal{B}_0=C$. And then, for sucessor ordinals $\lambda+1$ we define $$\mathcal{B}_{\lambda+1}=(\mathcal{B}_{\lambda})_c$$ and for limit ordinals $\eta$ we define $$\mathcal{B}_{\eta}=\bigcup_{\alpha<\eta}\mathcal{B}_{\alpha}$$
>
> **Claim:** Let $\Omega$ be the first uncountable ordinal. Then $\sigma(C)=\mathcal{B}_{\Omega}$

The demonstration of the claim is [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2603079/characterize-sigma-algebra-generated-by-a-set).

*First doubt*: my teacher said that this construction just hold if $C$ is the family of Lebesgue-measurable sets, but I can't see why who is $C$ matters at all... [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2603079/characterize-sigma-algebra-generated-by-a-set) $C$ is the family of open sets, but does that matter? So if $C$ doesn't matter can we say that this give us a method for characterizing any sigma algebra that is generated by a set?

*Second doubt*: I don't know much of ordinals. Is it $\Omega$ the only limit ordinal such that every countable subset of $[0,\Omega)$ has an upper bound in $[0,\Omega)$? Because it seems like if *yes* then we can prove that $\sigma(C)=\mathcal{B}_{\kappa}$ for any ordinal $\kappa$ that satisfies this assertion.

*Third doubt:* At step 2 of the answer (here $C$ is the family of of open subsets of $\Bbb{R}$), we could say $E=\Bbb{R}\in\mathcal{B}_0$, right? Of course it is in $\mathcal{B}_2$ also... but am I missing anything?

*Fourth doubt:* How can we prove that $(\mathcal{B}_{\lambda})_{\lambda}$ is strictly increasing??

I'm sorry if I am being too redundant in my question... But thank's in advance for any help!

Comment: (4) To prove **strictly** increasing.  Sometimes true, sometimes false, depending on the starting family $\mathcal C$.  The fact that it is strictly increasing for the case of open sets in $\mathbb R$ ... not easy, and not found in elementary books.

Comment: (3) Whether $\mathbb R \in \mathcal B_0$ depends on what the starting family $\mathcal C$ is.  But in any case, the whole space is in $\mathcal B_2$.

Comment: (2)  In general, $\mathcal B_\Omega$ is a sigma-algebra, and that shows that $\mathcal B_\lambda$ is unchanged for $\lambda \ge \Omega$.

Comment: (1) Yes, start with any [nonempty!] family $\mathcal C$ of sets, then this construction yields the sigma-algebra generated bt $\mathcal C$.

Comment: Alright! That helped me. Thanks! So by (2) we have that $(\mathcal{B}_{\lambda})_{\lambda}$ is strictly increasing until $\Omega$ and then become constant...